# xampp installation on centos 7

Tags: xampp, centos7

i am trying to run xampp on linux centos 7 and i am getting this errors.
[root@odoodemo /]# sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
/bin/sh: error while loading shared libraries: libdl.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/bin/sh: error while loading shared libraries: libdl.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: error while loading shared libraries: libdl.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/bin/sh: error while loading shared libraries: libdl.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/opt/lampp/bin/gettext: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

id: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/opt/lampp/share/xampp/xampplib: line 11: test: -ne: unary operator expected
/opt/lampp/bin/gettext: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
XAMPP: netstat: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I want to run xampp on centos 7